# Interfacing BMP280 Sensor with stm32l4

Tags: stm32, sensors, uart, i2c, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to read the pressure and temperature from the BMP280 sensor using STM32L476, but when i send them over UART to the TeraTerm terminal, it always shows 0 value for both pressure and temperature. Despite having 0 errors and 0 warnings when i build it, what possible mistakes i perhaps have done? I'm using the BMP280 drivers from here: https://github.com/ciastkolog/BMP280_STM32
Here's the main.c code:

```
include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "BMP280/bmp280.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
BMP280_HandleTypedef bmp280;

float pressure, temperature, humidity;
uint16_t size;
uint8_t Data[256];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  bmp280_init_default_params(&bmp280.params);
    bmp280.addr = BMP280_I2C_ADDRESS_0;
    bmp280.i2c = &hi2c1;


    bool bme280p = bmp280.id == BME280_CHIP_ID;
    size = sprintf((char *)Data, "BMP280: found %s\n", bme280p ? "BME280" : "BMP280");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, Data, size, 1000);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      HAL_Delay(100);


            size = sprintf((char *)Data,"Pressure: %.2f Pa, Temperature: %.2f C",pressure, temperature);
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, Data, size, 1000);
            if (bme280p) {
                size = sprintf((char *)Data,", Humidity: %.2f\n", humidity);
                HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, Data, size, 1000);
            }

            else {
                size = sprintf((char *)Data, "\n");
                HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, Data, size, 1000);
            }
            HAL_Delay(2000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 40;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Enable MSI Auto calibration
  */
  HAL_RCCEx_EnableMSIPLLMode();
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x10909CEC;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}
```

Comment: `bmp280_init()` needs to be called to initialize the sensor, and `bmp280_read_float()`/(`bmp280_read_fixed()`) reads the actual sensor values, like in the [example code](https://github.com/ciastkolog/BMP280_STM32/blob/master/Example_BMP280/Src/main.c). - In the code above the `pressure`, `temperature`, `humidity` variables are never initialized/changed and are therefore undefined (0.0f in your case). Do you call these functions elsewhere?

Comment: @rel I totally forget to add bmp280_read_float()/(bmp280_read_fixed() ! but even when i did, the variables are still not initialized and i get the error callback, to intialize the sensor i called 'bmp280_init_default_params(&bmp280.params)' as defined in the driver, is there any other way to it?

Comment: `bmp280_init_default_params()` only sets the values in the `bmp280_params_t` struct instance to default values, like you can see in [bmp280.c:55](https://github.com/ciastkolog/BMP280_STM32/blob/c3d7aeb2dede3412e66b376a11c28ef52539c81d/Example_BMP280/Src/BMP280/bmp280.c#L55). After that `bmp280_init()` needs to be called with that struct instance in order to initialize the sensor (like shown [here](https://github.com/ciastkolog/BMP280_STM32/blob/c3d7aeb2dede3412e66b376a11c28ef52539c81d/Example_BMP280/Src/main.c#L115)). By checking the return value you can verify if it is working/ready.

Comment: @rel  It still show the fail error even after that, do you think of any other issues that lead to the initialization failure? Really sorry for the bothersome

Comment: Did you get the "BMP280 initialization failed" error? If yes, verify that the SDA/SCL I2C pins are connected correctly to the STM32. Also check the SDO pin on the sensor (it sets the I2C address, BMP280_I2C_ADDRESS_0 means that it must be connected to GND). Is the I2C peripheral initialized correctly (check the `HAL_I2C_MspInit()` function in `stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c`). And compare the I2C timing configuration in STM32CubeMX with the information in section *5.4.2 I²C timings* in the [BMP280 datasheet](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bmp280-ds001.pdf).